# Use a custom domain instead of subdomain for a webapp that depends on the subdomain as a key

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record

I have a cloud application with subdomain per customer on Domain B.

- customer1.B.com
- customer2.B.com

Customer1 now wants to link to the application to use a subdomain of his own domain A. E.g. *app.A.com*

The cloud application depends on the subdomain (customer1), because it is using this as marker for loading the correct data. Is it possible in any way to "hide" the application behind another domain/subdomain (e.g. with CNAME)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Cname record would help to achieve the objective with name resolution.

(i.e.) a DNS query to customer1.b.com would receive a DNS answer pointing to app.A.com's IP address.

However, if request would be sent with hostname set as app.A.com and your webapp has a requirement to have the hostname set as customer1.b.com in order to retrieve correct data, then a hostname rewrite should be done at application level based on the setup and traffic flow